# MATLAB Neural network - how to generate a relationship/function out of it?

Tags: matlab

I have just tried out Neural Network fitting tool in Matlab, however, I am not able to generate a function which relates all the input variables to the output, can anybody help me out on this? Is there a post-processor available to do that?

cheers,
Gaurav

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If You are using nftool at the last page there are saving options.
You can generate script that will allow You to solve similar problem but with new fitting data and (what I think You want) You can save object with Your net that You can use with Your input to get output.

Answer (score 0):

The trained NN object itself can be used as the input-output function. It is an object that contains an "evaluate" method. See the example from mathworks for details:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/fitnet.html